# Filter based on multiple select values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a data with the format like this

```
const data = [
  {
    dealId: 1,
    name: "deal 1",
    funding_type: "D",
    category: "Industrials",
    status: "Funding",
    topic: "Latest"
  },
  {
    dealId: 2,
    name: "deal 2",
    funding_type: "E",
    category: "Financials",
    status: "Launching",
    topic: "Most Funded"
  },
  ...
]
```

I have four filter dropdowns and I am trying to filter multiple values at once, but I can only seem to filter one at a time. How can I achieve this ?

Here is my approach

```
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

 function myFilter(selectedValue, type, toFilterData) {
    return toFilterData.filter((item) => {
      const filter = {
        category: true,
        type: true,
        status: true,
        topic: true
      };

      if (type === "category")
        filter.category = item.category === selectedValue;

      if (type === "type") filter.type = item.funding_type === selectedValue;

      if (type === "status") filter.status = item.status === selectedValue;

      if (type === "topic") filter.topic = item.topic === selectedValue;

      return filter.category && filter.type && filter.status && filter.topic;
    });
  }

  function handleChangeTest(e, type) {
    const arr = myFilter(e.target.value, type, data);

    setFilteredData(arr);
  }

   return (

       <select
          id="filter-sector"
          className="input-field cursor-pointer"
          onChange={(e) => handleChangeTest(e, "topic")}
          onSelect={(e) => handleChangeTest(e, "topic")}
        >
          {topicOptions.map((sector) => (
            <option value={sector.value} key={sector.value}>
              {sector.placeholder}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
    
    // ... other selects

    filteredData.length > 0
      ? filteredData.map((d) => <div>{d.name}</div>)
      : null
  );
```

You can see my full code here [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-darkness-nn0mhw?file=/src/App.js:5643-6045)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was always filtering my original data and not the filtered data from other selected categories, changing my render function and onChange function works

Got some reference from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33618921/11866037)

```
function renderList() {
    let filteredItems = testData.data;

    ["category", "funding_type", "status", "topic"].forEach(function (
      filterBy
    ) {
      const filterValue = testData[filterBy];
      if (filterValue) {
        filteredItems = filteredItems.filter(function (item) {
          return item[filterBy] === filterValue;
        });
      }
    });

    console.log(filteredItems);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="filter-form">
          <FilterItems data={filteredItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-surf-sh5cww?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking in your filter if every props of your filter object is set to true ? Assuming your param type can have one value at a time something like the code below should work.

```
   function myFilter(selectedValue, type, toFilterData) {
    return toFilterData.filter((item) => {
        switch (type) {
            case "category":
                return item.category === selectedValue
            case "type":
                return item.funding_type === selectedValue
            case "status":
                return item.status === selectedValue
            case "topic":
                return item.topic === selectedValue
            default:
                return false
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your approach but it doesn't seem to filter multiple values at one, it's still filtering one at a time.